# Why do the compact and nested notations for classes/modules in Ruby behave differently?

Tags: ruby

I was looking at the Rubocop rule for module/class specification notations, and these two options exist:

```
# Style/ClassAndModuleChildren: EnforcedStyle: compact
module M::C

# Style/ClassAndModuleChildren: EnforcedStyle: nested
module M
  class C
```

The following two files, when run, show that the two are not identical in behavior (see the end of each file for output results):

```
# nested.rb

# Style/ClassAndModuleChildren: EnforcedStyle: nested

module OuterModule
  def foo; puts 'foo'; end
end

module OuterModule
  module InnerModule
    def hello
      puts 'hello'
    end
  end
end

module OuterModule
  class C
    include InnerModule
  end
end

# Does not produce any error when run
```

---

```
# compact.rb

# Style/ClassAndModuleChildren: EnforcedStyle: compact

module OuterModule
  def foo; puts 'foo'; end
end

module OuterModule
  module InnerModule
    def hello
      puts 'hello'
    end
  end
end

class OuterModule::C
  include InnerModule
end

=begin
  
❯ ruby compact.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  1: from compact.rb:15:in `<main>'
compact.rb:16:in `<class:C>': uninitialized constant OuterModule::C::InnerModule (NameError)
Did you mean?  OuterModule::InnerModule
  
end
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

It is because of a process called `constan lookup`. When ruby encounters a  constant token like `InnerModule`, it needs to find its assigned value. To do so, it checks the current "nesting" with `Module.nesting`.

`nesting` returns an array of modules we are currently nested in, but it can only be modified by keywords `class` and `module` (and has absolutely nothing to do with `self`, which might be a bit confusing). Each keyword prepends the module we're opening (and only that module) to the nesting:

```
Module.nesting #=> []

module A
  class B
    Module.nesting #=> [A::B, A]
  end
end

module A::C
  Module.nesting #=> [A::C] sic! no A
end

module A
  D = Class.new do
    Module.nesting #=> [A] sic! no module/class keyword = no nesting
  end
end
```

So, when looking for any constant, ruby will search for them in the "namespaces" from `Module.nesting` and their's included modules (and, if nothing is found, in `Object` - which is Ruby's top namespace).

This is why

```
class OuterModule::C
  include InnerModule
end
```

does not work. Ruby is only looking for `InnerModule` constant in `OuterModule::C` and global namespace.

It's also good to know, that new constants are always defined in the first namespace of `Module.nesting` - not `self`. This is quite common issue I see in RSpec tests:

```
RSpec.describe SomeClass do
  EXAMPLES = [1,2,3,4,5]

  ...
end
```

Even though `Rspec.describe` creates a new class in which the given block is evaluated, there is no `module/class` keyword meaning that all the constants defined within that block **are global**. So if you've ever encounter a large dose of "already initialized constant/previous definition was here" when running a test, it is most likely because of that.